# Can I override ES6's Promise by bluebird's implementation in node's global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, overriding, bluebird

I want to use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)'s implementation of the [Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) open standard and override [native ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I also want the bluebird implementation to be available everywhere in my subsequently imported modules without having to require it in every single one of them. Bluebird's [Getting started](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) page tells me to:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
```

, which results in overriding the native Promise element. Because bluebird is a superset of the spec, it will not break existing code and is thus supposed to be safe to use.

However, because I know it's considered bad practice to:

1. extend or replace language natives, and
2. define globals for use in a require chain that depends on it

, I'm wary when I want to include this in the base script of a node app:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
global.Promise = Promise;
```

Is this a bad practice? Should I stick to importing bluebird in every single file?

Comment: Just because I'm curious: Why do you want to override the base Promise implementation?

Comment: Generally faster, safer, better errors and incredibly helpful API add-ons. Check those out: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-bluebird.html http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html

Comment: > *I also want the bluebird implementation to be available everywhere in my subsequently imported modules without having to require it in every single one of them*. Why? `var Promise = require("bluebird");` is explicit, clear, self-documenting, and not magic.

Comment: @CrescentFresh I think Christophe means that all `require`d modules should also use Bluebird promises instead of native ones.

Comment: This is _not_ opinion based, this is a library question.

Comment: @gcampbell bluebird interops cleanly with other promise implementations, including native ones.

Comment: as info: if you use node, continual-local-storage and babel, you have bluebird monkeypatching, but not babel (shim) promises patch. Result: buggy cls or every file with const Promise = bluebird; and promisified libs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have done this hundreds of times in my code over the last 4 years and so have plenty others among the 10 million monthly downloads.

It is officially supported to swap the native implementation with bluebird.

I do

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
```

On a per-file basis. Note that usuaslly you can promisify your APIs once and then generally avoid calling `Promise` - calling at most `.resolve`.

Comment: I get an error by jsHint saying "Redefinition of promise", any ideas how to bypass this error?

Comment: @kamal0808 this github issue treats of your issue extensively https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1747

Comment: sonarqube treats is as major bug in the report saying ->  Remove this override of "Promise".